# Can I add new pods to existing service dynamically?

Tags: kubernetes

If I have a service that is running on a cluster, can I deploy and add some new pods to the service dynamically?

For instance, if the service has the label "app=MyApp", can the new created pods with the same label "app=MyApp" be managed by the service?

Comment: Is this just scaling up an existing application? Are you creating pods explicitly, or are you using a Deployment/ReplicaSet?

Comment: It is extension of application functionality (for instance, adding of a new service to application). The new pods are created explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - yes. And this is exactly what a kubernetes [replicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) enables, and these days you're most often encouraged to create one of those through a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/). Once created, you can scale up (or down) and the service will dynamically update it's internal forwarding based on the state of the pod's response to "Ready" (see the [docs for a readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)).

The [label/selector mechanism](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) that you're describing is exactly how that works within Kubernetes in a variety of places, and service <-> Pods that match is one of the most common